# BigCommerce API v3 Not getting product other detail Like mpn

Tags: bigcommerce

product Options MPN (manufacturer part number)- NOT SHOWING UP IN API.
We pull the product data through BigCommerce API and the MPN values for the product options is not come through.

Just to be clear the MPN under other details tab can be seen but the OPTIONS MPN's are not coming through. Recently Bigcommerce added the ability to assignee MPN's to options but it seems that it is not available in the API.

My question is am i doing something wrong or is this date just not available yet and are there plans to add this info in the IPA calls.

Answer (score 0):

The 'MPN' that is available with the Catalog API - GET /catalog/products/{product_id} is only the product's mpn, if your product has variants, these mpn values can be accessed via GET /catalog/products/{product_id}/variants.

These should help!
[Get Product with product MPN](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/products/getproductbyid),
[Get Variants with variant MPN](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-variants/getvariantsbyproductid)